# R loop eating up memory

Tags: r, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, officer

I am producing docx files using the `officer` library.
The database is not big (a few tens of lines and a few tens of columns).
After a certain number of iterations, the memory usage blows up and finally R crashes.

I cannot share the whole code and database, so I'm adding a kind-of skeleton code of the loop here. I hope it helps understanding the issue:

```r
datasource <- mydatasource
for(i in 1:nrow(datasource)){
  datasource_case <- as.data.frame(datasource[i,])
  datasource_case.melt <- melt(datasource_case[, id.vars=c(ID))

  assign(x="DOC_OUTPUT", value=read_docx(path=template_file), envir=.GlobalEnv)
  mygraph <- ggplot(datasource_case.ppa_melt.scale, ...)
  assign(x="DOC_OUTPUT", value=body_add_gg(DOC_OUTPUT, value=mygraph), envir=.GlobalEnv)

  rm(mygraph)
  rm(datasource_case.melt)
  rm(datasource_case)

  print(DOC_OUTPUT, target=outfile)
  rm(DOC_OUTPUT, envir=.GlobalEnv)

  gc(verbose=TRUE, full=TRUE)
  .jgc(R.gc = FALSE)
}
```

So, I'm trying to destroy all the objects after using them (even though they would be overwritten), and I also do `gc()`.

Yet, `gc()` reports:

```
Garbage collection 48 = 40+4+4 (level 2) ... 
58.1 Mbytes of cons cells used (55%)
15.0 Mbytes of vectors used (23%)
   > 2
Garbage collection 58 = 48+5+5 (level 2) ... 
58.1 Mbytes of cons cells used (55%)
15.0 Mbytes of vectors used (23%)
   > 3
Garbage collection 67 = 56+5+6 (level 2) ... 
58.1 Mbytes of cons cells used (55%)
15.0 Mbytes of vectors used (23%)
   > 4
Garbage collection 76 = 63+5+8 (level 2) ... 
58.1 Mbytes of cons cells used (55%)
15.0 Mbytes of vectors used (23%)
   > 5
Garbage collection 85 = 71+5+9 (level 2) ... 
58.2 Mbytes of cons cells used (55%)
15.0 Mbytes of vectors used (23%)
   > 6
Garbage collection 94 = 79+5+10 (level 2) ... 
58.2 Mbytes of cons cells used (55%)
15.0 Mbytes of vectors used (23%)
   > 7
Garbage collection 103 = 86+6+11 (level 2) ... 
58.2 Mbytes of cons cells used (56%)
15.1 Mbytes of vectors used (23%)
   > 8
Garbage collection 112 = 94+6+12 (level 2) ... 
58.2 Mbytes of cons cells used (56%)
15.1 Mbytes of vectors used (24%)
   > 9
Garbage collection 121 = 101+7+13 (level 2) ... 
58.2 Mbytes of cons cells used (56%)
15.2 Mbytes of vectors used (24%)
   > 10
Garbage collection 130 = 109+7+14 (level 2) ... 
58.2 Mbytes of cons cells used (56%)
15.4 Mbytes of vectors used (24%)
   > 11
Garbage collection 139 = 117+7+15 (level 2) ... 
58.3 Mbytes of cons cells used (56%)
15.8 Mbytes of vectors used (25%)
   > 12
Garbage collection 148 = 124+8+16 (level 2) ... 
58.4 Mbytes of cons cells used (56%)
16.6 Mbytes of vectors used (26%)
   > 13
Garbage collection 157 = 132+8+17 (level 2) ... 
58.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (56%)
18.4 Mbytes of vectors used (29%)
   > 14
Garbage collection 166 = 140+8+18 (level 2) ... 
58.7 Mbytes of cons cells used (56%)
22.2 Mbytes of vectors used (35%)
   > 15
Garbage collection 175 = 147+9+19 (level 2) ... 
59.2 Mbytes of cons cells used (56%)
30.4 Mbytes of vectors used (47%)
   > 16
Garbage collection 184 = 155+9+20 (level 2) ... 
60.0 Mbytes of cons cells used (57%)
47.6 Mbytes of vectors used (61%)
   > 17
Garbage collection 195 = 163+10+22 (level 2) ... 
61.8 Mbytes of cons cells used (59%)
83.7 Mbytes of vectors used (64%)
   > 18
Garbage collection 208 = 173+11+24 (level 2) ... 
65.3 Mbytes of cons cells used (62%)
160.5 Mbytes of vectors used (77%)
   > 19
Garbage collection 223 = 183+13+27 (level 2) ... 
72.3 Mbytes of cons cells used (56%)
321.7 Mbytes of vectors used (80%)
   > 20
Garbage collection 235 = 189+15+31 (level 2) ... 
86.3 Mbytes of cons cells used (55%)
659.3 Mbytes of vectors used (75%)
   > 21
Garbage collection 245 = 195+15+35 (level 2) ... 
114.4 Mbytes of cons cells used (58%)
1365.0 Mbytes of vectors used (73%)
   > 22
Garbage collection 255 = 199+17+39 (level 2) ... 
170.4 Mbytes of cons cells used (59%)
2837.6 Mbytes of vectors used (72%)
   > 23
Garbage collection 264 = 203+18+43 (level 2) ... 
282.4 Mbytes of cons cells used (58%)
5904.6 Mbytes of vectors used (72%)
   > 24
Killed
```

How can effectively prevent memory from blowing up?

My last resort would be to move the code from the loop into a separate script and call a new R session for every iteration, but that wouldn't be very elegant.

Comment: Please read https://github.com/davidgohel/officer/issues/184, you can use body_add_docx

Comment: Maybe try removing with rm() before the gc() all the objects that will be overwritten

Comment: @SantiagoI.Hurtado that is exactly what I am doing...

Comment: @DavidGohel, Thank You. In my case the issue was solved by proper variable scoping. I might still make use of body_add_docx later...

Answer (score 0):

(So... the first time that I answer my own question.)

Earlier, I had wrapped the `officer` calls in custom functions which were all reading and writing the global (`.GlobalEnv`) variables, including the one holding the large `officer` document.

Turns out that one of the functions made a **local copy** of the global variable, which was then:

- Not destroyed automatically by R when the function returned
- Not overwritten in memory when the function was rerun
- Not cleaned up by `gc()` (`gc()` was ran but did not help)
- Not removed by me until `rm()` (I did not include `rm()`)

...and it kept littering memory in a sort-of exponential fashion.

**The solution was, in my case, to avoid making a copy that is local to the function.** Alternatively, I think, **explicitly removing the object** using `rm()` would have worked too.

Now memory usage is flat and any number of iterations can be run safely.

Lesson learned. Don't count on others cleaning up your stuff.